# Lightning Web Component - how to update field for event.detail.row on onRowAction

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am working on lwc datatable where on click on a cell in the table I want to set a checkbox field as false for that particular selected record and pass it back to my original array with the updated value. Is it possible to update field of selected record with onRowAction?

I am new to this so I am not sure if this possible. I tried with the below code and it is not working:-

```
handleRowAction(event){
   const selectedRow = event.detail.row;

   if(selectedRow.checkboxfield === true){
      selectedRow = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) for inline editing.